# Ask explanation of one vim command

Tags: vim

In vim reference I saw this example:

```
:r !date<NL>-join
```

The `<NL>` should be typed as `CTRL-V CTRL-J`. I know date and join are external commands. I just can't explain what's the meaning of '-' before the join. The standard output of external command will created in temporary file, how the join take both the previous line in vim and this temporary file content and join them?May be I missed some knowledge in Vim command line.

Answer (score 3):

This command `:r !date^@-join` (Press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd> to type`^@`) contains two command:

- `:r !date`: read output of `date`.
- `:-join` (same as `:.-1join`): join lines. (`.-1` is a range. A single number can be used to address one specific line.)

---

```
:[range]j[oin][!] [flags]
                        Join [range] lines.  Same as "J", except with [!]
                        the join does not insert or delete any spaces.
                        If a [range] has equal start and end values, this
                        command does nothing.  The default behavior is to
                        join the current line with the line below it.
                        {not in Vi: !}
                        See ex-flags for [flags].
```